# sql query to fetch records with equal to and not equal to condition

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, where-clause

I have to fetch the records from the customer table where customer gift_type is only "cash" but those same customers should not have signed for "coupon" and "discount".below is my query it's not giving the exact records. more than 1 gift_type also gets included. I also tried using subquery, still doesn't work.

```
select cust_id from customer where gift_type='cash' and gift_type != 'coupon' and gift_type != 'discount';
```

&

```
select cust_id 
from customer c1, customer c2 
where c1.gift_type='cash' and c2.gift_type != 'coupon' and c2.gift_type != 'discount';
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: are you using oracle or mysql ?

Comment: iam using oracle

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.*
 from customer as c
 where c.gift_type='cash'
 and not exists
(
   select 1 from customer as x
     where c.customer_id=x.customer_id
      and x.gift_type in('coupon','discount')
)
```

Hope, the above is suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `not in` or `not exists`, as you want all customers which gift_type is cash, but at the same time those same customers must not exist in the table for the other gift types.

**Option 1**

```
select * from customer a
where a.gift_type = 'cash' and 
not exists 
( select 1 from customer c where a.customer_id = c.customer_id and c.gift_type in ('coupon' , 'discount' )
);
```

**Option 2**

```
select * from customer a
where a.gift_type = 'cash' and 
a.customer_id not in 
( select c.customer_id from customer c where a.customer_id = c.customer_id and 
  c.gift_type in ('coupon' , 'discount' )
);
```

Comment: the key field is customer_id

Comment: @HaameemShimar, updated for Oracle and key field customer_id

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single table scan using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT c.*,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN gift_type IN ('coupon', 'discount') THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) AS num_invalid
  FROM   customer c
) c
WHERE  gift_type = 'cash'
AND    num_invalid = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer (customer_id INT, gift_type VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO customer(customer_id, gift_type)
SELECT 1, 'cash'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'coupon'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'cash'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'discount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'cash'     FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER_ID | GIFT_TYPE | NUM_INVALID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | cash | 0 |

*Oracle [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dfa86d151c9de7eaf9ef5af1c4dd268c) MySQL [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfa86d151c9de7eaf9ef5af1c4dd268c)*